# Running a browser game in Java

Tags: java, controls, artificial-intelligence

I would like to know how I would kind of like run a online browser game, like tetris, as a Java application so I could control it (like in tetris using the wasd or arrow keys to move blocks) from within the application I program for the game. Not sure if that makes sense but don't know how else to explain it. The purpose is to hook it up to an AI program that plays the game, but yeah I don't know how to allow the program to control the game using the games allowed inputs.

Comment: This question as-is is very broad. You'll want to provide a [specific problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); StackOverflow won't write your project for you.

Comment: This is very broad. However, you might be interested in looking at the Robot class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Comment: I don't wish for anyone to write the project for me, I was just looking for a push in the right direction, which is what nasukkin and whatsGravity supplied. Thanks to you both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Java.awt.Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) seems to be what you need

It should be able to simulate any keyboard or mouse input, but if you need to do anything too complicated I would suggest something other than Java - it doesn't get too close to the operating system, so something like c++ may be more accurate.

Comment: What If I needed for multiple instances of the game to be controlled at the same time? I know how to access the URLS and open them in the browser but the robot class controls whats currently on screen right? So how would I control multiple at the same time?

Comment: Maybe have multiple windows open on the screen?

Comment: Yeah that could partially work. I guess that's as far as the robot class can go since it only connects to the browser remotely.